# How can I remove/change the icloud.com alias on my apple id account

Tags: apple-id

There are two email addresses listed in my apple id settings (section "REACHABLE AT"):

```
me@mydomian.com
my.oldname@icloud.com
```

The first is my login address. I want to change or remove the second one. How can I do this?

Comment: If you check your iCloud settings for Mail, is it checked? Alternatively, if you go to iCloud.com and select the Mail icon there, are you prompted to create an address? If you're not, its your iCloud.com email address and is permanent.

Comment: Yes it is the iCloud.com email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now **possible** to change the primary iCloud email address via Apple support if you can provide proof that you have changed your legal name.

See: https://www.selfawaresoup.com/notes/2020/11/24/removing-deadname-from-apple-id/

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not let you delete or change the primary iCloud email address. You can stop using it, but it'll always be associated with that account.

See also https://support.apple.com/ht202667, the section titled "If you can't change your Apple ID", which while is not the exact situation you're in, it explains how they look at it.